# Is there any possibility to create custom widget for Azure hosted API Management?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/new-azure-api-management-developer-portal-is-now-generally-available/

> Extensibility—The portal comes built into every API Management instance (excluding the Consumption tier). If you wish to extend the portal’s core functionality (for example, create your own widgets to fetch data from other sources), fork the GitHub repository, implement the code changes, and self-host your own modified version of the portal.

Is it so that we can't do custom widgets on Azure hosted Developer portal? If so, then this is a backstep from the legacy portal as there we could write custom HTML and JS to get custom features.

Comment: Yes that is correct, you need to fork the repository and create your own custom widgets and self host your portal.
I will not categorize this a step back from the previous version. 
The whole ideology behind this would be to keep the base portal simplistic and easy to set up. The extensibility and the open source nature of the portal allows you to modify it according to your own requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe still there are couple of things you can do.

Home page

The default Home page is filled with dummy content. You can either remove the whole sections with the content or keep the structure and adjust the elements one by one. Replace the generated text and images with your own and make sure the links point to desired locations.

Layouts

Replace the automatically generated logo in the navigation bar with your own image.

Edit the content of the portal, customize the website's look, and publish the changes.

Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal-customize and let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a pull request to the repository.
If you create a custom widget and this will be useful for many users it can be included in the default set of widgets.

Answer (score 0):

We can add custom widget to the managed developer portal now . Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/developer-portal-extend-custom-functionality).